# Excel 2016. How to show specific value on Userform1 from a sheet?

Tags: excel

[image: Sheet][image: Form]I'm a novice in VBA and with help of few users of this site I've managed to do few things. @Lambik was helping me resolve/achieve this but because of my own fault the question got all muddled up. He did got one thing working for me for that I'm very thankful. I can only apologies for my lack of knowledge on how to properly format code in the replies section. Having said that, I still need help with this thing. I'm a networks person and Excel and VBA is not my command field and that's why your patience is highly appreciated.

The workbook contain 12 sheets. One for each month of the year. Months are selected using a combobox (drop down list/menu). Upon selecting the month on the user form the data is entered into the relevant sheet. January or February or any for that matter (based on the selection from the combobox).

On user form I need to show column G last row's value. How do I go about it? @Lambik asked me to post the full code and that's where I made the mistake and entered it in the replies. It looks like C+ to be honest. So on user form I can add a textbox on which the user can see the value which is in there. I'll post the code and try to maintain the formatting.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next

End Sub
```

The code for CommandButton1 is,

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim dcc As Long
   Dim abc As Worksheet, pfl As Worksheet

  Set abc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
  Set pfl = Sheets("ProfitLoss")

   With abc

   dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value

End With

With pfl
dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
End With

TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox3.Text = ""
TextBox4.Text = ""
TextBox5.Text = ""


End Sub
```

OK I have tried my best to keep both codes in format and not to miss anything out so for anybody who tries to help/contribute can easily understand things.

Now what's needed is to show value from sheet on to the user form. I made a TextBox6 for this purpose only. On the January sheet and all other sheets the Column is G where the value is. Row is changing every time an entry is added.

Your help is very much appreciated. I can not post pics I think. I tried few days ago and site said I can not post, yet. I really hope I've not left out anything which is worth mentioning. Your time and effort is appreciated. I'm on laptop and can try any suggestions/code straight away. Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers.

P.S. Every function works at the moment, from selection of months to entering data and data going in correct rows and such. No errors whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE following the remarks of OP:

The value you want shown needs to be in a **textbox** (and not a label) and needs to be the one of the **active sheet**.

However, you said the user should not be able to change the balance value on the userform, therefore a label is better than a textbox, as a textbox is meant to be changed and a label is not.

The code is modified to show the desired value in a textbox

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Set wsActive = Activesheet
LastRow = wsActive.Cells(wsActive.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row

'TextBox 1 carries the desired value
TextBox1.Value = wsActive.Cells(LastRow, 7).Value

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next

End Sub
```

Of course, ensure that the textbox below the label "balance" is named Label1!

If you want to use a label, as I suggest, change:

```
TextBox1.Value = wsActive.Cells(LastRow, 7).Value
```

into

```
Label1.Caption = "Balance is: " & wsActive.Cells(LastRow,7).Value
```

To update, as requested, the value of the caption whenever the combobox is changed, add below the private sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim SheetName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

SheetName = ComboBox1.Value
Set ws = Sheets(SheetName)

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Label1.Caption = "Balance is: " & ws.Cells(LastRow, 7).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Am I glad to see you @Lambik you are right all sheets from Januarytill December have same columns. Only change is in Profit and Loss sheet which you helped me in the morning. I tried this code and nothing happened. No value show nor any error. Am I correct in saying that your code will show value of last row of G from profit and loss. What I need is last row value from the any of the current sheet, from January to December, Not the profit and loss sheet. PL sheet is mostly done manually only few entries are copied from active sheet which you helped this morning. I hope I didnt confused you.

Comment: Can I post a pic/screenshot? Much easier for me because I have posted all the code which is in UserForm1 and nothing else. I struggle with excel terms I don't have a background of it. I'm in networks and I don't know why I took this upon me to make this. Workbook have 13 sheets, 12 for months (each for one month) and one PL which I added in the morning. Select the month from combobox1 and data will enter in that sheet. Whatever the last row value of Col G that is what needs showing in Textbox6 (I textbox on userform). I really hope you can figure it out because for me I'm not making any sense!

Comment: I tried fiddling with the code and I worked but since the value is from profitloss sheet and not from the current sheet in which data is entered, its not good enough. I understand that it can work because this did worked. I had to use ' in one of the existing code line and then it worked. The only thing I can not understand is how to auto read the value from whatever sheet is in the background in which the data was entered. Set pfl function is above my pay grade lol. Sigh this has become a mission lol. I hope it can work, somehow. Thanks for your help @Lambik I appreciate it very much. Cheers

Comment: see edited answer. pfl was not a function. You choose a variable, now called wsActive, but it can be anything you want, you dimension it as a worksheet and then you attribute a value to that variable 'set wsActive = Activesheet'

Comment: Morning @Lambik OK many thanks for the explanation, I'll give it a go now and get back to you in a few. Cheers.

Comment: You nailed it @Lambik it's what I intended it to be. It worked straightaway with a minor hitch. It shows the balance value correctly but when I change the month from combobox1 (list of months) the balance is not updating/not showing the value of february 2019 last row of G. It shows it if I close the form and make february 2019 sheet active manually and then start userform1 again, then it shows correct value. Changing the drop down list doesn't update the Label8. I went ahead & used your recommendation of using label and not textbox. You're right it's the way to go. I appreciate your help!

Comment: It works and I'm happy. But how to do we make it to update automatically when the month is selected/changed after an entry from the combobox1?

Comment: see edited answer, please mark as answered when correct :)

Comment: That's it! Perfect! The value of Label8 changes based up on the selection of Combox1. I really appreciate your help, effort and time which you invested in this. Many thanks and a good weekend to you!! Cheers.

Comment: I have another question but I need to go out so will post it later lol. Appreciate your patience and help. Cheers.